# Loaded JSON documents into Azure CosmosDB via DTUI, how do I mass-convert Documents so I can query with LINQ?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I had a few thousand JSON documents that I bulk loaded into CosmosDB using the DTUI utility.

I have since reverse engineered a C# object model from said JSON documents.

I am trying to query the collection in LINQ using my C# types, and I'm assuming that's because everything is just a CosmosDB Document.

Is there anyway of converting/mapping all the documents in my collection so that they're recognized as my C# types?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway of converting/mapping all the documents in my
> collection so that they're recognized as my C# types?

This is something that is taken care of by the SDK for you. As you mentioned, the documents stored in Cosmos DB is in JSON format. What you have to do is create equivalent classes in your code and the SDK will do map the document to your C# class using JSON serialization.

For example, let's say I have a following document in Cosmos DB:

```
{
    "id": "bcd1f574e8f94034fed7c245130c2b65",
    "firstName": "Gaurav",
    "lastName": "Mantri"
}
```

What I would need to do is create a model that will map to this document. Something like:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class User
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "firstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

When I query my container, I will instruct SDK to map the document to this model. Something like the following:

```
FeedIterator<User> resultSetIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<User>("Select * from root r where r.id = 'bcd1f574e8f94034fed7c245130c2b65'");
while (resultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    FeedResponse<User> users = await resultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
    foreach (User user in users)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"User id: {user.Id}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {user.FirstName} {user.LastName}");
    }
}
```

Above code will print the following on the console:

```
User id: bcd1f574e8f94034fed7c245130c2b65
Name: Gaurav Mantri
```

Here's the complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace CosmosDbSQLAPISamples
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string connectionString = "connection-string";

        private static string databaseId = "database-name";
        private static string containerId = "container-name";

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(connectionString);
            Container container = client.GetContainer(databaseId, containerId);
            FeedIterator<User> resultSetIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<User>("Select * from root r where r.id = 'bcd1f574e8f94034fed7c245130c2b65'");
            while (resultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                FeedResponse<User> users = await resultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
                foreach (User user in users)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"User id: {user.Id}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {user.FirstName} {user.LastName}");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "firstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```